# How to find minio objects by tag?

Tags: tags, minio

I am using minio `mc` client. There is possible to use `mc find` command to find minio files or objects. But I can't find how to find or filter files by theirs tags. Any idea?

```
NAME:
  mc find - search for objects

USAGE:
  mc find PATH [FLAGS]

FLAGS:
  --exec value                  spawn an external process for each matching object (see FORMAT)
  --ignore value                exclude objects matching the wildcard pattern
  --name value                  find object names matching wildcard pattern
  --newer-than value            match all objects newer than L days, M hours and N minutes
  --older-than value            match all objects older than L days, M hours and N minutes
  --path value                  match directory names matching wildcard pattern
  --print value                 print in custom format to STDOUT (see FORMAT)
  --regex value                 match directory and object name with PCRE regex pattern
  --larger value                match all objects larger than specified size in units (see UNITS)
  --smaller value               match all objects smaller than specified size in units (see UNITS)
  --maxdepth value              limit directory navigation to specified depth (default: 0)
  --watch                       monitor a specified path for newly created object(s)
  --config-dir value, -C value  path to configuration folder (default: "/Users/kolisko/.mc")
  --quiet, -q                   disable progress bar display
  --no-color                    disable color theme
  --json                        enable JSON lines formatted output
  --debug                       enable debug output
  --insecure                    disable SSL certificate verification
  --help, -h                    show help
```

```
NAME:
  mc - MinIO Client for cloud storage and filesystems.

USAGE:
  mc [FLAGS] COMMAND [COMMAND FLAGS | -h] [ARGUMENTS...]

COMMANDS:
  alias      set, remove and list aliases in configuration file
  ls         list buckets and objects
  mb         make a bucket
  rb         remove a bucket
  cp         copy objects
  mirror     synchronize object(s) to a remote site
  cat        display object contents
  head       display first 'n' lines of an object
  pipe       stream STDIN to an object
  share      generate URL for temporary access to an object
  find       search for objects
  sql        run sql queries on objects
  stat       show object metadata
  mv         move objects
  tree       list buckets and objects in a tree format
  du         summarize disk usage recursively
  retention  set retention for object(s)
  legalhold  manage legal hold for object(s)
  diff       list differences in object name, size, and date between two buckets
  rm         remove objects
  version    manage bucket versioning
  ilm        manage bucket lifecycle
  encrypt    manage bucket encryption config
  event      manage object notifications
  watch      listen for object notification events
  undo       undo PUT/DELETE operations
  anonymous  manage anonymous access to buckets and objects
  tag        manage tags for bucket and object(s)
  replicate  configure server side bucket replication
  admin      manage MinIO servers
  update     update mc to latest release
```

Answer (score 1):

S3's ListObject API does not return object tags, hence you can't use `mc find` to query tags. Instead you have to use `GetObjectTagging` S3 API to get tags of an object.

```
GET /{Key+}?tagging&versionId=VersionId HTTP/1.1
Host: Bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-expected-bucket-owner: ExpectedBucketOwner
x-amz-request-payer: RequestPaye
```

Comment: Is this doable using minIO package?

Answer (score 0):

in MinIO client you can use this command:

```bash
mc find --tags="tag=value" AliasMinIOName/BucketName/
```

for example:
my alias MinIO name is myminio
my bucket name is sample
my tag key, tag value are key1=value1

finally:

```
mc find --tags="key1=value1" myminio/sample/
```

list all objects in sample bucket that have `key1=value1` tag.

Answer (score 0):

> --tags
>
> Optional
> New in version mc: RELEASE.2023-04-12T02-21-51Z
>
> For use with MinIO deployments only.
>
> Return objects with a tag that matches a specified RE2 RegEx pattern. Use the format --tag="KEY=regexValue".
>
> You can pass a key with an empty value. In that case, mc find matches
> objects that do not have the metadata key or where the metadata key’s value is empty.
>
> You can use the flag multiple times to match objects for additional tags. To return, an object must have matching values for all tags.